# How do I get a column from mySQL to show up in a select box via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, listbox, drop-down-menu

I have a form with one select box (pulldown list).  I need to get a column from mySQL to appear in the select box.  How do i make the connection? Are there any examples out there?

Comment: Select box? Are you talking about PHP?

Comment: you mean like this: http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// connect to MySQL
$query = "SELECT <col> FROM <table>";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<option>{$row['<col>']}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

If you need to have the first option empty, just print this line after the `select` tag:

```
<option></option>
```

Comment: How do I make the first option blank?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've not clearly understood, what ever you want to say, but you can try the below solution.

```
<select name="example">
<?php
// Database connetcion goes here
$q=mysql_query("SELECT option1 FROM table"); /// where option1=the column you want to show
while ($sql=mysql_fetch_row($q)){
echo "<option value='".$q['0']."'>".$q['0']."</option>";
}
/// keep this code block wher you want to show the pull down select box
?>
</select>
```